# Upgrade status module not working

Tags: 8

I am trying to run upgrade status module to find out the errors of incompatible modules. but i am unable to click the scan selected button. i cant select the button in admin side. Is there any other way to check the modules

[image: scsreenshot of error]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because when you can't click something that's supposed to be clickable it's a bug that must be filed with the module's issue queue on drupal.org. Though I'm not sure if it's really a bug. Maybe you didn't install the module's dependencies right. It's important to provide all steps to reproduce this error. Like how did you install the module exactly, in what version, to what version of Drupal, what version of PHP etc.

Comment: Also what does you can't click the button mean exactly? Any errors in the console? Or maybe some overlapping CSS? Can you click the other buttons?